# Max size of a message OpenShift / Node.js can serve?

Tags: node.js, http, openshift

I have a web service called `fetchAllRecordChanges` running in `OpenShift` platform written in `Node.js`. Sometimes it can return plenty of data. Is it any limitation in `OpenShift`, or in `Node.js` that can prevent data to send to the client? Or any `HTTP` protocol limitation?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you using openshift default router there would be some parts of the configuration that can affect your requests [1], but it's highly unlikely that this would affect typical node.js app.

I would check default configuration in your node.js web framework (express.js etc.)

[1] https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/images/router/haproxy/conf/haproxy-config.template#L328